# how to use heartland-nodejs module in nativescript angular application?

Tags: npm, nativescript, node-modules, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to use **heartland-nodejs** module in nativescript angular application it shows the following error while importing

> `var heartland = require('heartland-nodejs');`
>
> System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException:
> System.err:
> System.err: Error calling module function

In Nativescript they are giving an option to use NPM modules in nativescript application....

[How to Use any npm Module with NativeScript](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/how-to-use-any-npm-module-with-nativescript)

Comment: You can't use NPM modules which depend and use the builtin Node.js API.

Comment: I can use moment NPM module in nativescript...  Is possible to build nativescript plugin using NPM Modules...

Comment: Did you read what I wrote? You can't use modules relying on builtin node.js APIs. Clearly momentjs doesn't, which is what allows you to use it inside of NativeScript apps.

Comment: I just use the following line to check...  it Gives me expected result.... `this.timeStamp = "Generated on " + moment().format('LL') + " at " + moment().format('hh:mm:ss a');
`

Comment: Can u give any other suggestion to use heartland payment gateway in Nativescript Angular App...